# PHP спарсить строку

Tags: php, строки

У меня есть такое в PHP:

```
$balance = {"1KQWEd5atQMKKRMbNoeiznkKM82mn5Rgmr":{"final_balance":482400,"n_tx":146,"total_received":112338968}}
```

Как мне спарсить именно число 482400 на PHP? Какие есть способы?

```
$balance = {"1KQWEd5atQMKKRMbNoeiznkKM82mn5Rgmr":{"final_balance":482400,"n_tx":146,"total_received":112338968}}    
$arr = json_decode($balance, true);
print_r($arr["final_balance"]);
```

Такой код не работает

Comment: вы видимо, потеряли кавычки. это называется json посмотрите описание функции json_decode

Comment: $obj = json_decode($balance);
 print $obj->{'final_balance'};

Я пробую сделать вот так, но ничего не выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтоб взять значение по первому индексу в массиве, можно воспользоваться функцией current

```
$balance = json_decode($balance, true);

echo current($balance)['final_balance'];  //  482400
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Comment: А если например по 2 индексу нужно будет или по 3?

Comment: можно получить массив индексов array_keys() и взять нужный индекс оттуда. Или сделать цикл по массиву со счетчиком и отбирать нужный